# Unable to enter VR mode with krpano project

Tags: javascript, xml, oculus, krpano, webvr

### Description

Hello, I'm currently following [krpano oculus rift tutorial](http://krpano.com/forum/wbb/index.php?page=Thread&postID=58228#post58228). Everything about the krpano is working, except for the fact I am unable to get it to run in VR mode.

### What I've tried

To get the html running in VR mode with the Oculus Rift I need to:

1. Download and install one of the experimental web browers. I chose FirefoxNightly ( which does work with the [krpanos online demos](http://d8d913s460fub.cloudfront.net/krpanocloud/webvr/index.html?v=119pr1) ).
2. Add a "Enter VR" button and add an onclick to run `enterVR`

I've also checked and the webvr plugin is installed and active on my firefox nightly.

### Errors

In my console I am getting this error when I click my button.

> ReferenceError: enterVR is not defined

### Questions

What am I am I doing wrong/missing for it to work?

There is this one part of the tutorial that I didn't quite understand.

> Stereoscopic rendering support (output side): The stereoscopic
>   rendering will be either enabled automatically when using the WebVR
>   Plugin and calling the enterVR() action ...

The WeBVR Plugin is a clickable elment that links to [this](http://krpano.com/plugins/webvr/#syntax) page. They start talking about `webvr.js` and possible attributes for an xml page.

```
<plugin name="WebVR" devices="html5" keep="true"
        url="webvr.js"
        worldscale="1.0"
        mousespeed="0.00125"
        mobilevr_support="true"
        mobilevr_ipd="63.5"
        mobilevr_screensize="auto"
        mobilevr_lens_fov="96"
        mobilevr_lens_dist="0.6"
        mobilevr_lens_vign="100"
        mobilevr_webvr_dist="false"
        mobilevr_sensor_mode="3"
        mobilevr_fake_support="false"
        vr_cursor=""
        vr_cursor_onover=""
        vr_cursor_onout=""
        onavailable=""
        onunavailable=""
        onunknowndevice=""
        onentervr=""
        onexitvr=""
        />
```

Does the webvr plugin ( the one that comes with firefoxnightly ) include all the above or not? If it doesn't how do I find this `webvr.js` and how do I include it in my project ( or firefoxnightly ) with the xml file?

These may be very simple questions, but I have been spending many hours trying to figure it out with no success. I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Got some help and was able to figure it out.*

Before I get started, everything I tried earlier ( and that I mentioned in the question ) was completely wrong. Forget everything I wrote and just follow this.

### Vital information

[image]

In your `krpano-1.19-pr1` you'll notice a `viewer` folder which itself has a `plugins folder`. In this plugin folder you will find the following vital files necessary for your VR to function correctly:

1. `webvr.xml`
2. `webvr.js`
3. `webvr_cursor_80x80_17f.png`

### Solution

You need to copy these three files and place them in your generated vtour plugin's folder.

[image: krpano tutorial 2]

You need to **open tour.xml** and **add two lines** ( *I believe you can do this before or after you modify your tour.xml file via the tour_editor.html interface* ):

```
<!-- webvr.xml - WebVR plugin, enter/exit VR buttons, VR cursor, VR setup -->
<include url="%SWFPATH%/plugins/webvr.xml" />

<!-- add/overwrite some settings from the webvr.xml for this example -->
<plugin name="WebVR" mobilevr_fake_support="true" />        <!-- enable the FAKE VR support to allow testing also on desktop and tablets without VR support -->
```

These lines need to be added at the beginning of the file after:

```
<krpano version="1.18" title="Virtual Tour" onstart="startup();">
```

[image: krpano tutorial 3]

The two lines just tells krpano the location of the three new files you've added to your plugins folder.

### End result?

These lines will enable you to go into VR mode. No you do not have to add a button in the tour.html file, it does that automatically now just like in the demo.

Hope this will help others that came across the same problem.